# GCP app-engine flex 502 error

Tags: google-app-engine

I've inherited a setup using app-engine flex and (afaik) this means our api gateway is managed. Last week were getting a 502 from NGINX. We ultimately solved it by redeploying but I want to understand what happened.

Where might I be able to see logs for this? Do I have any control over the NGINX setup? Could I have just restarted the api gateway instead?

Thanks

Comment: Can you see the logs using the Stackdriver Logging [ https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview ] and selecting your GAE application?

Comment: Could be this case, "All flexible instances are restarted on a weekly basis. During restarts, critical, backward-compatible updates are automatically rolled out to the underlying operating system. Your application's image will remain the same across restarts." so it will return 502 while it restarts on periodically.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something that should raise with  [tech support](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164). Remember to provide your Project Number and **not** your Project Id as it is [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information).